# Qual condição posso desenvolver para evitar duplicar valores?

Tags: javascript, while, matemática

Como evitar números duplicados neste gerador aleatório?

```js
var soma = 0
while (soma < 1000) {
    soma += parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
    document.write(soma + "<br>")
}
```

Conforme vai executando, chega num dado momento que ele traz consigo incidências de valores.

Comment: Tens de resitar os valores que já foram "sorteados" algures. Quantos numeros unicos queres? entre 0 e 1000?

Comment: @Sergio Então [Sergio](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio), seria deixar apenas um único número entre 0 e 1000. Por exemplo: 0 1 2 4 7 9 ... e evitar duplicação de valores 0 1 1 2 4 7 9 9 9 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugestão:

Dentro do `while` gera um numero e verifica se ele já existe dentro da array que guarda os numeros sorteados.

Caso exista faz `continue` para o `while` continuar, caso não exista, adiciona-o à array e acrescenta-o na `soma`.

```js
var soma = 0;
var sorteados = [];
while (soma < 1000) {
  var nr = parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10) + 1; // +1 para não aceitar "zero"
  if (sorteados.indexOf(nr) > -1) continue;
  soma += nr;
  sorteados.push(nr);
  console.log('Soma:', soma, 'Sorteado:', nr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar este código:

```js
var soma = 0;
var numeros = [];
console.log('Soma: ' + soma);
while (soma < 1000) {
   numero = Math.random() * 100;
   if (numeros.indexOf(numero) < 0) {
       numeros.push(numero);
       soma += parseInt(numero);
       console.log('Soma: ' + soma);
   }
}
```

Comment: Mas ainda continua repetindo. Você poderia ajustar sua solução, afim de melhorar?

Answer (score 1):

Funciona utilizando `indexOf` como foi mostrado, porém seria mais eficiente(em termos de uso de memória) utilizar uma `Hashtable`, dessa forma:

```js
var soma = 0;
var sorteados = {};
while (soma < 1000) {
   var num = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
   if (!sorteados.hasOwnProperty(num)) {
     sorteados[num] = true;
     soma += num;
     console.log(soma);
   }
}
```

Obs: Não é recomendável utilizar a função `document.write` pois isto reescreve todo seu DOM, ao invés disso você deve utilizar o javascript para recuperar elementos do seu DOM e adicionar valores ou outros elementos a ele.

Comment: Concordo com você, com as novas mudanças do [ECMAScript](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript). Mas para ilustrar o(s) exemplo(s) acho ainda Útil tanto o `alert()` quanto `document.write()`. Mas ta valendo sua colocação!